# Custom filetype per file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Let's say that i have file `/home/foo/myfile` without extension. Is there option to add syntax setting into this file? In *vim* it's `:set syntax=javascript`. I know that in Sublime you can set default syntax color.
There's similar question [Changing default syntax based on filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100634/changing-default-syntax-based-on-filename) but there you set specific filename. I need to set it in file itself, since i have a lot of different files without extension.

Answer (score 1):

The package [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) should be able to do what you want.

> ApplySyntax is a plugin for Sublime Text 2 and 3 that allows you to
>   detect and apply the syntax of files that might not otherwise be
>   detected properly. For example, files with the .rb extension are
>   usually Ruby files, but when they are found in a Rails project, they
>   could be RSpec spec files, Cucumber step files, Ruby on Rails files
>   (controllers, models, etc), or just plain Ruby files. This is actually
>   the problem I was trying to solve when I started working on this
>   plugin.

Set your rules/filenames in the `ApplySyntax.sublime-settings` file:

> // "rules" is a list (array) of checks that you want to make against
>   the file in the  current view. A rule is either a regular expression
>   or a function. If using a  regular expression, **you can specify
>   whether you want it tested against the  "file_name" or the first
>   line of the file (think shebangs and xml files)**. If the  rule is a
>   function, you must provide the path to the file containing the 
>   function and the name of the function to call. When this function is
>   called, the  "file_name" will be passed to it as the only argument.
>   You are free to do whatever  you want in your function, just return
>   True or False.

Comment: Sounds promising. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

you can do this on the fly through the command menu (on OSX `cmd+shift+p`, windows `ctrl+shift+p`) then type what you need (e.g. javascript) and it will come up in the list `set syntax: JavaScript`.

Sublime will remember this until you close the file

Comment: Is there option to add `set syntax: JavaScript` into this file so that everytime i open it will understand it's JavaScript