# Sublime Text Syntax Detection with non-dot-separated extensions

Tags: sublimetext3

I am cross-developing applications for a system that does not use a dot to separate file name from extension, but rather an underscore.

Is there a way to make Sublime Text detect this "_" separated extension as an indication of file type? Like have it detect

```
 main_c
```

as a file type of "C" for syntax highlighting?

I know that I can set the file type manually, I also know that I can set a file type per file, but that's simply a work-around. I would like to have ST detect the type on its own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom filetype per file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775559/custom-filetype-per-file)

Comment: @KeithHall It's actually not. I *know* how to set a custom file type per file. But I want the program detect it on its own, I just have no dots...

Comment: the question itself may not be an exact duplicate, but the answer to that question, (use a plugin called "ApplySyntax") seems like it should be applicable here, as one can set regex rules on which to use. A bit of a pain, I guess, having to configure each extension manually, but you could always write your own plugin - in either case, a plugin is needed to achieve what you desire.